# startx results in error "timeout in locking authority file /home/myaccount/.Xauthority"

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, x-windows, xauth

About once a month, I try to start X windows on my local desktop with:

```
   startx
```

but the terminal seems to hang, then gives the error:

```
   xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/myaccount/.serverauth.8280
   xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/myaccount/.Xauthority
```

I tried all the methods people have suggested when I looked up this error:

1. Make sure the permissions for .Xauthority belong to myaccount

   Delete the .Xauthority file before doing startx

Lately though, those methods did not work.  I then saw that there were some files in my home directory that were read only.  Because of this, I realized that my home directory itself somehow did not have the correct permissions for me to even create files.

So based on the instructions at:

```
   https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1276517
```

I did:

```
   chown -R myaccount:myaccount /home/myaccount
```

and now I can start X windows.

I don't know why this happens every few weeks since nothing has changed about the OS.  The only thing I can think of is that sometimes I ssh in to my desktop and this causes some kind problem
to my account.

I am posting this here because I didn't see this as a solution to the .Xauthority problem, and it may be of benefit to someone.  I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 6.7.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,  sukces,  that was wired prowilidges of authority,  and delete it can help or second method what I try was changing it to user mode.